# Capture network traffic from Playstation

Tags: wireless-networking, ps3, packet

I want to capture network traffic from my playstation.  It is connected to my wireless network.  For some reason Ethereal (now WireShark) isn't letting my use my wireless card to see traffic.

Is it a driver issue?  Do I need a different wireless card?  Even if it did work would I be able to accomplish my goal like this?  Can I use a wired connection to get the packets being sen

Comment: We can't tell you any answers if you don't tell us the full question. What is your current wireless card? What drivers? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely down to the limitation of either the driver of the wireless card or most likely the wireless card itself. When I need to do this sort of thing, I use my wireless USB card.

If Wireshark simply cannot access the card, this is why. If however you can access it but just can't see any data, try changing the wireless mode to open / non password as some advanced types of encryption do not easily allow for spying on connections.

Lastly, an alternate solution may be (if it is a standard/ssl web request), to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and then put the ip of your machine as the Play Station's gateway and intercept that way.

Comment: I will give it a try - thanks.  I will also try out my usb wireless card and see if it shows up.